# Android Tracking App - check if someone is getting closer or distancing from specific point

Tags: android, location, tracking

I created an android app, which stores user's home location and count distance between home and his/her actual location, in a Service class.

Now I would like to programme feature that would decide based on counted distance, if a user is:

- at home
- away
- getting closer
- distancing from home

This should be similar to Google Now, that can predict that you are for example going home. If someone had some examples, I would be sooo grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement such kinda work, you need to implement `GeoFence` in your android app.

`GeoFence` gives you idea about user entered/exited from a defined area. If you set home location as base location and radius to 500m then it gives you entered callback you are within 500m of your home.

When you go away 500m from your home location then it gives you exited callback. To know about whether you are home location then at a interval of few minutes you can poll GPS coordinates then can identify whether you are at your home location.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html